# Subir archivos a una carpeta en la red local de Windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estoy tratando de subir archivos a mi carpeta compartida en mi red local con asp.net c# en WinForms pero no he tenido éxito

He buscado información en internet pero no encuentro mucha información acerca del tema, el código que pongo de muestra solo sube el archivo y crea una carpeta con la ruta que le establezco, la cual debe ser la ruta de la carpeta compartida aparte de que lo hace en la raíz del proyecto, pero lo que quiero es subir los archivos a la carpeta compartida para que otros usuarios dentro de la misma red puedan ver esos archivos.

```
string strFileName;
        string strFilePath;
        string strFolder;
        strFolder = Server.MapPath("Ruta de mi carpeta");
        
        strFileName = ftpFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
        strFileName = Path.GetFileName(strFileName);

            
            if (!Directory.Exists(strFolder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strFolder);
            }
            
            strFilePath = strFolder + strFileName;
            if (File.Exists(strFilePath))
            {
                lblComprobante.Text = strFileName + " already exists on the server!";
            }
            else
            {
                ftpFileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(strFilePath);
                lblComprobante.Text = strFileName + " has been successfully uploaded.";
            }
```

¿Existe manera de subir archivos a esa carpeta compartida?

Comment: Qué pasa al usar ese código? Algún mensaje de error? Estalla en llamas?

Comment: Saludos Luis, sí existe manera de subir archivos a carpetas compartidas en red. Por otro lado, edita la pregunta y agrega todos los detalles de lo que has intentado, errores que te da el código actual y demás, aquí unas sugerencias que te ayudarán a mejorar la pregunta, ergo, mayor chance de obtener respuesta. https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Primero, pedirte que aclares esta confusión, pues diría que o es asp.net o es winforms, pero no las dos a la vez, pues una se ejecuta en el escritorio y la otra en la web. Por otro lado, dices ["no he tenido éxito"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/21), pero no dejas los mensajes de error que se ven, ya sea en tiempo de ejecución o de compilación, o el comportamiento erróneo que tiene el código que publicas. Por favor lee [ask].

Comment: Listo ya formule mejor mi pregunta

Comment: @Alfabravo el código crea una carpeta y sube el archivo seleccionado a la raíz del proyecto y lo que quiero es subir archivos a  una carpeta compartida para que otros usuarios dentro de la misma red puedan ver esos archivos

Comment: @jachguate No he tenido éxito debido que la información  que he encontrado crean los archivos en la carpeta del proyecto

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de la ruta, posiblemente sea hay el inconveniente que la ruta no se esta generando correctamente e igual me gustaría que colocaras con que nombre se esta guardando el archivo en la carpera del proyecto

Comment: Igual podría ser tu error que este mandando el archivo mal ya que al menos cuando exporte agrego el patch de SaveAs le agrego // para especificar que el archivo estará dentro del folder de esta manera $"{rutaArchivo}\\{nombreArchivo}"

Comment: @JonathanJimenez  esta es el ejemplo de la ruta Server.MapPath("\\servidorlocal\\CarpetaCompartida");

Comment: @JonathanJimenez tambien he provado de la siguiemte manera : @"\\servidorLocal\CarpetaCompartida"

Comment: @JonathanJimenez el archivo y la carpeta los crea en el mismo nivel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba crear el path del archivo con una barra de raiz `\` en medio de las dos variables así:

```
strFilePath = strFolder + @"\" + strFileName;
```

Otro punto en esto, y un explicación a
sobre las rutas de directorios.

Veo en esto, un par de cosas a comprobar, primero guardas la nombre de archivo del `ftpFileUpLoad.PostedFile.FileName` en `strFileName`, y justo en la siguiente linea, guardas con `Path.GetFileName()` el nombre del archivo de `strFileName`, en `strFileName`.

```
strFileName = ftpFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
        strFileName = Path.GetFileName(strFileName);
```

- Comprueba, visualiza en tu proyecto en tiempo de ejecución estos valores, y verifica que `ftpFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName`
  te esté devuelviendo una ruta de archivo completa,
  y no solo un nombre de archivo (.. .FileName(?)), para mantener la linea que le sigue, ya que Path.GetFileName() espera como parámetro una ruta de archivo, no solo un nombre de archivo ..
- Y otro asunto es, una ruta de directorio, es valida para crearlo o acceder a este, sin importar que termine o no termine en un `\`. Mientras que para hacer esto ...

strFilePath = strFolder + strFileName;

Debes comprobar visualmente, o de algun modo al menos, las cadenas que estas uniendo/sumando para obtener una ruta de archivo valida ..

Porque en este caso solamente puede servirte, comprobar que el método que sea al que pides la ruta de la carpeta (destino) (strFolder), te devuelve esa ruta de carpeta con un `\` al final ((?) Es improbable, salvo que el metodo este hecho para que lo haga de esa forma específicamente);

Ya que la ruta de una carpeta, como tal termina en el nombre de la carpeta, de modo que es lo mas seguro que esa sea la forma en que te la esté devolviendo el método.

Y asegurarte sino es que ya trae esa barra `\` de colocarla tu entre medio de las dos variables así ..

```
strFilePath = strFolder + @"\" + strFileName;
```

Como en este ejemplo, el directorio, es sin la barra al final, por lo que ya se la añado para obtener la ruta que quiero.

Visualiza lo que estas tratando de utilizar como cadenas de ruta de un directorio y nombre de archivo con el proposito de obtener una ruta de archivo valida, y al menos descartar un fallo con esto.

[image: Como en este ejemplo, el directorio, es sin la barra al final, por lo que yo se la añado para obener la ruta]